# admin url auto redirect magento 2

Tags: magento

I have a problem with magento 2. When I setup completed magento2. I go to admin url:

```
http://m2_test2.local/admin_9gtqm8
```

It auto redirect to:

```
http://m2_test2.local/admin_9gtqm8/http:/index/m2_test2.local/admin_9gtqm8/admin/index/index/key/cf2582b28cecd5d388bd4d2044110919a7e40940cbd833cb93d5e5e01fc8ccae/
```

and I can't access admin. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Clean up a bit, still probably needs some more info from the OP.

Comment: you setup using composer terminal or from GUI?

Answer (score -3):

[image]- Clear cache by empty var/cache folder
- app/etc/config/local.xml should have admin url. If it is not the same, add the same url there as well.

```
&lt;admin&gt;
        &lt;routers&gt;
            &lt;adminhtml&gt;
                &lt;args&gt;
                    &lt;frontName&gt;&lt;![CDATA[admin_9gtqm8]]&gt;&lt;/frontName&gt;
                &lt;/args&gt;
            &lt;/adminhtml&gt;
        &lt;/routers&gt;
    &lt;/admin&gt;
```

- Clear browser's cache by hitting ctrl + shift + delete keys at once.

This should get you going.

Comment: `app/etc/config/local.xml` , where to find this?

Comment: from your magento installation directory

Comment: do you realy think its exist their ? I dont find it .

Comment: I attached image. You can check that. I have magento community edition.